# Run script every time HDMI connects/disconnects on Fedora 36?

Tags: fedora, gnome, display, hdmi

I want to run a script every time my HDMI is connected or disconnected, is there any tools that allow me to this? I'm using Fedora 36 with GNOME 42 on Wayland.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30808466 https://superuser.com/a/449307 (without pkill -P) and everything else Google finds: https://www.google.com/search?q=tail+grep+run+command Unfortunately I've no idea which file to grep because most likely you're running a Gnome Wayland session, so there's no `Xorg.log` file.

Comment: `udev` can do this. See this [Archwiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev#Execute_when_HDMI_cable_is_plugged_in_or_unplugged)

Comment: @FelixJN would this work on wayland or only Xorg?

Comment: `udevadm monitor`  will show you what is happening. You can then decide what to do when a device is `removed`, `added` etc..

Comment: `udev` by now is a default part of `systemd` and *directly talks to* the kernel. Your display server is independent from that.

Comment: @FelixJN I tried to add the rule but for some reason it isn't working. I did a simple rule just to check if it's working: `ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", RUN+="touch /home/user/check"`. I reloaded udev `sudo udevadm control --reload`  and even restarted my laptop but still doesn't work. Any ideas? Edit: Obviously I replaced `user` with my actual username.

Comment: Anything in the logs? Also use the full path of the executable. `/usr/bin/touch` or matching.

Comment: @FelixJN apparently the PATH variable was not set, that was my mistake. Now it works but I'm still trying to figure how to run the script after the change happens. Now the script is running before the change happens (When I connect my monitor for example, my script would `cat /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status > /file` to check if the script runs after or before connecting the display and the output is `disconnected` however I would expect, since I'm connecting the display, that the output was `connected`. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: How about using separate commands for `ACTION=add` and `remove` instead of the generic `change`? But you say `before` the change - which does not make sense since the trigger comes with the change. Are you sure the script has no error? Does is maybe need a 1-second delay?